# Problem when trying to install Sharepoint 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm following the guide from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

STEP 2 has instructions:

---

Extract the installation files by opening a Command Prompt window, and then typing the following command at the directory location of the folder where you copied the installation files in the previous step.

For SharePoint Foundation 2010:

c:\SharePointFiles\SharePoint /extract:c:\SharePointFiles

For SharePoint Server 2010:

c:\SharePointFiles\OfficeServer /extract:c:\SharePointFiles

---

My question is - If I'm only supposed to copy setup.exe , then where does OfficeServer come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions are for the executable version of the installer. The ISO image does not require this step. Just copy the all files / folders from the ISO image to HDD.

Answer (score 1):

The installers are named 'Setup.exe'(SharePoint Server 2010) and 'SharePointFoundation.exe'(for Foundation). The commands listed do *not* reflect those names.

The right commands are:
For SharePoint Foundation 2010:

```
c:\SharePointFiles\SharePointFoundation.exe /extract:c:\SharePointFiles
```

For SharePoint Server 2010:

```
c:\SharePointFiles\Setup.exe /extract:c:\SharePointFiles
```

(disclaimer: i'm not able to test test this right now!)

---

It is a trick available to most windows installers, it will extract the files zipped/cabbed in the installer.

Comment: Doesn't work, but thanks!